# Plot data in Grafana Time Series

Tags: time-series, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm facing an issue while working with Grafana and CloudWatch. Specifically, I have metrics being pushed to CloudWatch, and when I try to visualize the data in Grafana, I encounter a problem with grouping the metrics by name.

In CloudWatch, I can successfully group the metrics by name, resulting in a single data point in the time series. However, in Grafana, the time series appears to be spread out and not properly grouped.

I have attempted to explore different configurations and options within Grafana to achieve the desired grouping, but have been unsuccessful thus far. I would like to know if there are any specific settings or techniques that I can utilize in Grafana to achieve the same grouping behavior as in CloudWatch.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and properly group the metrics by name in Grafana would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[Grafana Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHPl8.png)

[Cloudwatch Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quRa2.png)

I tried grouping the data by date using dateformat but was still not able to achieve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.